# Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Installed:

```
kafka_2.11-2.1.0 and zookeeper-3.4.13
```

Run:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Run Connector:

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
```

Executed:

```
echo '{"name":"load-kafka-config", "config":{"connector.class":"FileStream-
    Source","file":"config/server.properties","topic":"kafka-config-topic"}}' |
    curl -X POST -d @- http://localhost:8083/connectors --header "content-
    Type:application/json"

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8083: Connection refused
```

Output Connector:

```
    [2019-03-08 13:04:43,839] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109)
[2019-03-08 13:04:43,839] INFO Kafka commitId : 809be928f1ae004e (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110)
[2019-03-08 13:06:43,854] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:117)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:58)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

How can I configure the **default** Kafka download to avoid the error and start the Connector in distributed mode and also making the REST interface accepting commands?

I am using the default configurations for Connect:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

All files: https://bitbucket.org/powder366/kafka_problem/src/master/

Comment: `Check worker's broker connection`, so  in `connect-distributed.properties` how are you specifying the broker location?

Comment: Which value do you you exactly mean? Added link for my config files. This should really be configured out of the box from the Kafka guys. Standalone works.

Comment: Config looks OK. Is your Kafka broker definitely up?

Comment: If you want "configured out of the box" have a look at https://www.confluent.io/download/ and run `confluent start`.

Comment: Yes Kafka and Zookeeper is running. Distributed Connect also comes up. After issuing the REST command the error comes after 30 seconds (don't know if it's related). Also the REST get a connection refused. I have Confluent up and running. Will test the same thing there eventually or even just use Standalone Connect for now.

Comment: Make sure Kafka remains up... The `__consumer_offsets` topic replication factor may also need changed in `server.properties`

Comment: Kafka is up. Replication is only needed for safety if something goes down in a production environment, as I know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that localhost was not included in the default configuration:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
```

Also adopted files to get it to work according to (standalone, distributed, multi-broker):

Demo: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

New files: https://bitbucket.org/powder366/kafka_working/src/master/